# .htaccess ignored on Windows 7 with Apache 2.4.10

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts, apache2.4

One of our development environment uses Windows 7 (with Apache  2.4.10). I have setuped mod_rewrite, and created a virtual host to point to my `project` (can access on `project.local`), but the `.htaccess` does not works properly. When I go to `project.local/css/styles.css` (which is an existing folder and file) all works fine. But when I try to access a rewrited URL like `project.local/account/login` I see a 404 page and the request is not mapped to `index.php` as per rule defined inside `.htaccess`.

If I write the `.htaccess` file content wrong purposely and try to access `project.local` or an existing file like `project.local/css/styles.css` I get an Internal Server Error (as expected), but when I access `project.local/account/login`, the 404 error continues, which means that `.htaccess` is ignored.

No error log found.

**C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

**C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@project.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/webroot"
    ServerName project.local
    ServerAlias project.local
    ErrorLog "logs/project.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**C:/xampp/htdocs/project/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you see something wrong? I have spent almost a day on that without success.

Comment: If you get Internal Server Error when you make intentional syntax errors, then `.htaccess` is not being ignored.

Comment: Even when I access `/account/login` and get 404 instead of 500, @ÁlvaroG.Vicario?

Comment: When you set all this up, did you restart the apache service?

Comment: I was just clarifying that ".htaccess is ignored" and "my rules for mod_rewrite do not work as expected" are different problems.

Comment: For sure @PanamaJack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/` some alias was conflicting with my application route. I have removed these unecessary alias and all works fine!

```
<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /account "C:/xampp/account-system/htdocs"

    [...]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a different document root in your VirtualHost file. That might be causing some issues.

Try changing your VirtualHost to this and then restart the Apache service. Then check your rewrite rules.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@project.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/webroot"
    ServerName project.local
    ServerAlias project.local
    ErrorLog "logs/project.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/project.local-access.log" common
   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/webroot">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or you can try changing your rewritebase.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project/webroot

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```